# Excel Macro : How can I get the timestamp in "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" format?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `DateTime.Now` in my Excel Macro to show the current timestamp.

It shows timestamp in "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" format.

Instead, how can I get the timestamp in "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" format?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Try  with: `format(now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 44):

`DateTime.Now` returns a value of data type `Date`.  Date variables display dates according to the short date format and time format set on your computer.

They may be formatted as a string for display in any valid date format by the `Format` function as mentioned in aother answers

```
Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 4):

If some users of the code have different language settings format might not work. Thus I use the following code that gives the time stamp in format "yyymmdd hhMMss" regardless of language.

```
Function TimeStamp()
Dim iNow
Dim d(1 To 6)
Dim i As Integer


iNow = Now
d(1) = Year(iNow)
d(2) = Month(iNow)
d(3) = Day(iNow)
d(4) = Hour(iNow)
d(5) = Minute(iNow)
d(6) = Second(iNow)

For i = 1 To 6
    If d(i) < 10 Then TimeStamp = TimeStamp & "0"
    TimeStamp = TimeStamp & d(i)
    If i = 3 Then TimeStamp = TimeStamp & " "
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked best for me:

```
        Cells(partcount + 5, "N").Value = Date + Time
        Cells(partcount + 5, "N").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this format **yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss** in format cells by clicking customs category under Type

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp in saving workbook path, the "`:`" needs to be changed. I used "`:`" -> "`.`" which implies that I need to add the extension back "`xlsx`".

```
wb(x).SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & unique(x) & " - " & Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yy, hh.mm.ss") & ".xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Format function below:

```
$(get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmmss)
```

Answer (score -1):

It can work as easy as this, choose the location you want, in this case I choose D3

```
Sheets("Put your Sheet's name here").Range("D3") = Now
```

Example, my sheet is called `Sources`

```
Sheets("Sources").Range("D3") = Now
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the Format function.

```
Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")
```

Comment: Don't work! `Date` contain only the calendar date but the hour, minutes and seconds are fixed to 0:00:00 ! You have to use `Now()` instead..